# Why are some addition reactions syn and some anti?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

Is it experimentally observed or do we know proper reasons for why some addition reactions are syn and some anti?

Like for halogenation to a double bond, I believe that the ring formed will cause hindrance and so only anti can be formed.
But for hydrohalogenation, either can happen. Is this because there is no hindrance in any case?

Similarly for hydrogenation, it is always syn? Why is that? What is the mechanism behind hydrogenation?

Comment: As you have correctly surmised, the stereochemistry is controlled by the reaction mechanism. In the case of halogenation, addition to the halonium intermediate is by an $S_N2$ type reaction so the resultant stereochemistry must be anti. In the case of hydrogenation, the reaction happens at a metal surface, with both hydrogens added from the same side of the double bond.

Comment: I see, what about HX (hydrohalogenation)?

Comment: I want to say it's because the intermediate is a planar carbocation so there is no selectivity of attack but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: There can be ion pair effects in the addition of HX which favour syn addition but attack at both sides can (and will) occur. The ratio will depend on the exact substrate, solvent, reaction conditions etc. For catalytic hydrogenation, the addition is always syn and the mechanism is easily available online, look it up yourself.